# How to change DCOM config identity programmatically by powershell script?

Tags: powershell

How to change DCOM config identity programmatically by PowerShell script? I got the respective class but password parameter is not exposing.

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting `
              -Filter 'Description like "%the name which you want to search%"'
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by _"the password parameter is not exposing"_ Can you please clarify?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this directly from PowerShell.  I think using the `DcomPerm` tool is the way to go.  Obtaining it is a bit of a pain as it was only released as a code sample in the SDK, but there are various places online offering the compiled version (if you trust them!), or there is a [community version](https://github.com/albertony/dcompermex) you can try.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If you're trying to set what's on the Identity tab in `dcomcnfg.exe` (Component Services), then I'm not sure if that's exposed to WMI at all. If you're trying to set the password, you can do that with `dcomcnfg.exe` ([example here](https://serverfault.com/q/530472/77656)). If you're trying to view or set who can launch, configure or access a DCOM application, then you're looking for [WMI methods on the Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-dcomapplicationsetting).

Comment: Thanks for reply I am trying to modify the password of docom config components for my application. Actually manual steps is right click on the components select properties go to Identity and set the new password. I want to automate the steps. I got the command and the required class but password parameter is not exposing. Command is as follows.      Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting `
              -Filter 'Description like "%the name". If anyone can help me it will be helpful.

Comment: Can u please help me with the above query or the approach if can any one explain.